# How to modify the Unity TextMeshPro Input Field Caret?

Tags: unity, text-mesh-pro

the default caret doesn't match the style of our font at all, ideally i would replace it with an upper case "i" that uses our main Font material, is there a way to do that ?

searching the internet only gave me these 2 results:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/custom-caret.662905/

https://gist.github.com/DrSharky/f35ebbe39f31bc842c98bd09da01d45d

Which imo are both dirty ways to "manually" put a character in the right position while hiding the original caret, and the first link doesn't even work for TMP because the **cachedTextGenerator** doesn't exists in TMP.

My main question here is where does TMP or Unity UI text get the "blinking caret" character from ? is it from the system ? or is it embedded in the font asset ? can i override that somehow ?

Thanks!
Thanks!